# Set Django project default port

Tags: python, django

I have multiple Django projects being used as individual services, they are then all used by each other in return.

This then means all the services are set running on individual ports which can be a bit unreliable as I need to remember when starting the project with

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Ideally for each project I would just use the `runserver` command and it would know which port to run on automatically.

Is this possible without the need of bash aliases?

Comment: Why u need this without bash aliases because u have to register the port somewhere by this way or by another way. And why dont u use an application server something like gunicorn? Because as django developers says u must not use django test server at production and **using an application server solves your problem**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well beyond the scope of what the development server should be doing. If you need to run your apps in a way that they can actually talk to each other, even in development, you should probably be using a more configurable server. Gunicorn would be ideal. Then you could use something like Foreman (or the Python port, [Honcho](http://honcho.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)) with a Procfile that lists all the apps and their ports, then start the whole thing with a single command.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: that information has to be stored somewhere. Hence you could put it in a configuration file and make a script that loads the appropriate host and port to run. The `manage.py` file doesn't support a particular configuration file so you'll need to do this outside of `manage.py. The script would then call`manage.py runserver host:port` with the correct details.

Answer (score 0):

I have ever tried to do this, I thought maybe I cound the set default port in the `setting.py`.

When I dug a bit to the code, I found that the default port number is defined in `django/core/management/commands/runserver.py`. It's used by all django projects, so you can't set individual default ports for different django projects.